# es lint max length rule disabling is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I am trying to disable eslint rule in a typescript file. I have a regular expression which contains more than 500 characters. So it's generated an eslint warning. Since this is a regular expression, better way is to add an eslint comment before declaring the regular expression only for that line. So my attempt is as below.

```
/* eslint-disable-next-line max-len */
export const URI_REGEX = "" // something which is very long
```

But still this is not working. I could see the eslint warning as `This line has a length of 509. Maximum allowed is 270`. So how can I remove this warning?

Comment: I think to disable the next-line you cannot use block quotes `/**/`. Use `// eslint-disable-next-line max-len`

Comment: other way also tried out. not works. But inline comments working

Comment: What do you mean by _"inline comments"_?

Comment: You also may want to also rethink why you need a regex that is 500 characters long. That sounds like a nightmare to maintain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure, your method should be working but can you give this a try by wrapping it?

```
/* eslint-disable max-len */ 
   export const URI_REGEX = "" // something which is very long
/* eslint-enable max-len */
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of eslint do you have?
I think you can can try `//eslint-disable-line` for disable all rules for the specific line, or using `// eslint-disable max-len`

Taking from here: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/3375

**Edit**

I think you can also add a ignoreRule for you speisifc regex. See here the docs: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-len of **ignorePattern**

Comment: still not working. I am using eslint `7.32.0` version

Comment: But inline comments working